# Limit involving Gamma function

Tags: limits, gamma-function

I've seen a really interesting result, namely :

$$\underset{s \to 0}{\lim} \Gamma(s) - \frac{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}{2} =-\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

This was computed by Wolfram|Alpha, but can someone give some insight on how the $\gamma$ constant appears? What manipulations can one use in cases like this, when the argument of the Gamma function $\rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: $\Gamma{(s)}=\frac{1}{s}-\gamma +o(s)$ when $s\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{s\to 0^+}\left(\Gamma(s)-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\right)=\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(s+1)-\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)}{s}\tag{1}$$
hence by applying De l'Hopital theorem and exploiting $\Gamma'(z)=\psi(z)\,\Gamma(z)$ we have:

$$ L = \psi(1)-\frac{1}{2}\psi\left(1\right)=\frac{\psi(1)}{2}=-\frac{\gamma}{2}\tag{2}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using L'hopital rule by writing
\begin{align*}
\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(s+1)-\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)}{s}&=\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(s+1)-\Gamma(1)+\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)-\Gamma(1)}{s}\\
&=\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(s+1)-\Gamma(1)}{s}+\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\frac{s}{2}\to 0^+}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)-\Gamma(1)}{\frac{s}{2}}\\
&=\Gamma'(1)-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma'(1)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma'(1)=-\frac{\gamma}{2}.
\end{align*}